# Examine the convergence: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\sin\frac{a}{n}(a\gt 0)$ (I solved but not sure if it is correct)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a question that I don't know if I solved it correct.
Can you check and show me the right way?

Question:
Examine the convergence of series given below:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\sin\frac{a}{n}\space (a\gt 0)$$

---

My answer:

1. (absolute convergence): i) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert (-1)^{n-1}\sin\frac{a}{n}\rvert =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\frac{a}{n}\space a\gt 0$$ (can take positive and negative values)
2. (conditional convergence) $$\rightarrow Should\space not\space be\space absolute\space convergent$$$$\rightarrow Alternating\space series\space should\space be\space convergent\space too$$$$Alternating\space series\space test:$$

   - For every $n$, $a_n$ is positive $x$
   - For every $n$, should be $a_n\gt a_n-1$
   - $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$

$\space$
3.step: It is Divergent

Comment: What has the sine function to do with your original series?

Comment: Because if I'm not wrong, sin function can not converge to a specific value

Comment: You gave a NUMBER series. This either converges or diverges, there is no remainder, nor its behaviour....and that sine there has no business at all here. I think you want to ask something else, so try to clear your intention **or** write down the whole question.

Comment: My bad! Ah... I wrote the first part of the question and gave you second part's answer.

Comment: corrected the question

Comment: How did you get the equality between the two series in your 1.? The absolute vale of any number is non-negative. I do not understand your reasoning in 2.

Comment: @Gary from absolute convergence test? The goal of this test is to get rid of $(-1)^{n-1}$, isn't it?

And reasoning in 2 are rules, at least we have learned like that.

I am open to your better approaches, by the way.

Comment: $\left| {( - 1)^{n - 1} \sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} \right| = \left| {\sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} \right|$ which is not necessarily ${\sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)}$. What you can say is that the terms eventually alternate: when $\frac{a}{\pi } < n$, $\sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right) > 0$ holds indeed. Also, please write $a_n$ instead of $an$.

Comment: I am confused... since my main language is not English it is even harder to understand.

I will edit the post; however, can you show me the exact steps for solving this problem? Because my mind just does not help, I get stucked with getting the sin out of the absolute value.

And I know if you show me only one step, I will ask further... that's why I want exact steps. So that I can learn and say "Huuuh, that's the way it should be done!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N = 2\left\lceil {\frac{a}{\pi }} \right\rceil$ and write
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n - 1} \sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {( - 1)^{n - 1} \sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)}  + \sum\limits_{n = N + 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n - 1} \sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} .
$$
The first part is a finite sum, hence it converges. For the second, note that by the choice of $N$,
$$
\sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right) > 0
$$
for all $n\geq N+1$. Also, $\sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right) \to 0$ strictly monotonically, whence by the alternating series test, the second sum converges. Accordingly, your original sum is convergent. It is not however absolutely convergent. To see this, note that for $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $\sin x>\frac{2}{\pi}x$. Thus,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left| {( - 1)^{n - 1} \sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} \right|}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left| {\sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} \right|}  \ge \sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty  {\left| {\sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} \right|}  \ge \frac{{2a}}{\pi }\sum\limits_{n = N}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}} .
$$
But we know that $\sum\nolimits_{n = N}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}}$ is divergent, whence $\sum\nolimits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left| {( - 1)^{n - 1} \sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} \right|}$ must be divergent too. Consequently, the series is not absolute convergent.

Comment: How is first part is a finite sum, isn't it infinite?

Comment: It is a sum from $n=1$ to $n=N$, hence finite.

Comment: Why do we have an N? Where does it come from?

Comment: I split the series at $N$ into two parts. In the second part (infinite sum) it will then be guaranteed that the sine function is positive. This is because for $n\geq N+1$, $0<\frac{a}{n}<\pi$ (by the choice of $N$).

Comment: OK, I got it.
Thank you. Only the last part I have a problem with. 
How did you show that original sum is not absolutely convergent, I mean which test did you use at the end that comes after "thus" AND how we have "$\sin x\gt\frac{2}{\pi}x$", how did you get that \sin x is greater than $\frac{2}{\pi}x$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of absolute convergence? When do we say that a series $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely? For the question on sine, $x \mapsto (2/\pi) x$ is just the segment connecting the points $(0,0)$ and $(\pi/2,1)$ (for $0\leq x \leq \pi/2$) and it is below the graph of the sine in that interval.

Comment: As long as I know, we put original sum into absolute value and if we find out it is divergent, there is a chance that it can be a conditional convergence.

Comment: You take the absolute value of the terms and not the whole sum: $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely if and only if $\sum |a_n|$ converges. In your case, I showed that $\sum |a_n|$ is divergent (by comparing it to the divergent tail of the harmonic series) hence $\sum a_n$ is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Then... I don't understand why we write n=2N under the sum symbol.
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left| {( - 1)^{n - 1} \sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} \right|}  = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\left| {\sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} \right|}  \ge \sum\limits_{n = 2N}^\infty  {\left| {\sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)} \right|}  \ge \frac{{2a}}{\pi }\sum\limits_{n = 2N}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}} 
$$
these parts

Comment: For $n\geq 2N$, $0<a/n<\pi/2$ so I can use that lower bound for the sine. Clearly, if I leave out the first $2N-1$ terms from a series with non-negative terms, I get something less (hence $\geq$).

Comment: If you think I answered your question, you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: I still have questions in my mind, I didn't forget about it.

Can you apply alternating series test to the second part of the sum?

I still don't know how did we get $\sin x \gt\frac{2}{\pi}x$ and how did we get $n=2N$... For a nutshell, I still have problems showing why it is not an absolute convergence.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did for the part $$\sum\limits_{n = N + 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{n - 1} \sin \left( {\frac{a}{n}} \right)}.$$

Comment: Alternating series test has 3 conditions:
1. For every $n$, $a_n$ is positive
2. For every $n$, $a_n\gt a_{n+1}$
3. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\space a_n=0$

That's how I learned. And I can't see how you managed to apply this test. Can you show me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109067/discussion-between-gary-and-colleg-an-delta).

Comment: Why are we splitting series at N into 2 pieces?
Your early explanation for this "In the second part (infinite sum) it will then be guaranteed that the sine function is positive." includes N in itself.
I mean writing it kinda makes sense but it is the first time I'm seeing such a thing. I couldn't understand the reason why.